# Load data from CSV file into OrientDB

Tags: sql, csv, orientdb2.2

Is there any command to load one whole CSV file on OrientDB.

My CSV file looks similar to this -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Orientdb has an etl module.

The documentation is https://orientdb.com/docs/last/ETL-Introduction.html#